# Two dimmer switches installed in double gang box

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, junction-box

I have two ceiling lights in my kitchen. Each lamp has its own dimmer switch in the same junction box.
It is very tight/crowded in the box. I cannot tighten the switches without them being misaligned. I cannot get the switch cover onto the switch box. There is no room to maneuver. How can I make some room to make a better fit in the box and to properly secure the outer switch plate?

Comment: Can you post a picture with the cover off so we can see what you see? You will probably have to pull the switches out of the box, with the power off, and reposition any wire nut off to the sides of the box to make more room for the switches.

Comment: The dimmers can take a bit more side to side space than normal toggle switches.  you may be able to find thinner dimmers to replace the ones your using. or better, get a special double dimmer that has both switches in a 'single gang' profile.

Comment: Are the lamps on the same circuit (one breaker turns off both of them)?

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the two dimmers with a single narrower double dimmer will allow them to fit easier  a dual gang box.  They are technically made for a single gang box, but will definitely fit in a dual box. Here is an example, there are fancier ones available as well.

[image]

Comment: Great solution as long as the 2 lights are on one circuit, which is most likely the case but not guaranteed.

Comment: wow,  i didnt even consider that separate circuits would be feeding the two dimmers in the same box.  is that really ever done?

Comment: Very unlikely. But *technically* possible. A dual switch (dimmer or not) will often have the hot wire common, so it is a concern.